# How to select in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Have an issue

Examle

```
ID      ID2

1       100  

3       100

5       100

1       110

2       110

4       110




select * from table where ID in (1,4) ---executing not correctly

select * from table where ID = '1' and ID = '4' ---not work
```

I need that ID2 will '110' (select ID2 which have 2 value ID)

Thanks.

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: Do you need IDs that have more than 1 corresponding ID2s? Or you need ID2s whose count is more than 1?

Comment: @jim I need IDs that have more than 1 corresponding ID2s

Comment: @user2943856 see new answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have few ID's you can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ID, ID2
FROM dbo.Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table1 t2 
   WHERE t2.ID=1 AND t2.ID2=t1.ID2
)
AND EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table1 t2 
   WHERE t2.ID=4 AND t2.ID2=t1.ID2
)
AND ID IN (1, 4)
```

This returns the two records  that have the same ID2 and ID=1 **AND** ID=4.

```
ID  ID2
1   110
4   110
```

[**Demo-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a4aa6/6/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID FROM (
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID2) as cnt FROM Table) t
WHERE t.cnt>1
```

Comment: But where are ID  `1` and `4` that OP uses in both of his approaches?

Comment: @TimSchmelter author's description of the problem was not clear enough for me. I assumed his 1 and 4 were just for example. His final answer in comments thread was "I need IDs that have more than 1 corresponding ID2s" so i did the job. He can add any filter in the inner query very easily.